# MySql Update Case Cannot be null

Tags: mysql, case

I have a problem with a update with cases

I have a table called diccionary

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id   |  table_name   |  col_name |  size    |   precis   | data_type  |
+------+---------------+-----------+----------+------------+------------+
|  1   |  'user'       |  'id'     |  null    |   10       |  'int'     |
|  2   |  'user'       | 'name'    |  255     |   null     |  'varchar' | 
|  3   |  'user'       |'lastname' |  255     |   null     |  'varchar' |
|  4   |  'user'       | 'age'     |  null    |     2      |  'varchar' |
```

I tried to use this query

```
UPDATE diccionary SET
size = CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 250 END,
data_type = CASE when id = 4 THEN 'int' END;
```

but i get this error

```
#1048 - Column 'data_type' cannot be null
```

what is wrong in my query? Thanks

Comment: You miss the else part in case. So if id not 4 then data_type will be null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the data_type column cant'be null so you just manage the case when not equal to 4 eg: assigning varchar

```
UPDATE diccionary 
SET size = CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 250 END,
data_type = CASE when id = 4 THEN 'int' ELSE 'varchar' END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, if the column is not null you need a default value. Try adding and 'ELSE' in the condition:

```
UPDATE diccionary SET
size = CASE WHEN id = 2 THEN 250 END,
data_type = CASE when id = 4 THEN 'int' ELSE '????' end;
```